# im getiing fwrite() when i try to send email through laravel

Tags: laravel, email, mailtrap

I was sending normal until I start getting this error

```
fwrite(): send of 18 bytes failed with errno=10054 An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.
```

this is my .env

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=4fe075e8cb5300
MAIL_PASSWORD=5800191ac8e718
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=hello@example.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

FILESYSTEM_DRIVER=public
```

and this is my config file

what is the problem here

Comment: check you smtp config files `config/mail.php`, url and ports set correctly or not, if you think correct share config and .env files here, also share how you send email

Comment: i didnt change any thing in the config file ... the code was working normally until start to give this error

Comment: check if you exceeded mailtrap limit for emails

Comment: no i didnt i have sent just 4 messages befor